# Resume bullet point incorrectly aligned in between two lines

Tags: enumerate, itemize, bullets

I am trying to build a resume but when I use itemize with subheading, the bullet point comes in between two lines, I want it horizontally beside the top line. The tex file is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{turnthepage}
\usepackage{array}



%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Edit these values as you see fit

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{1pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.95}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.95}  % Inner background color of title bars


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Margin setup

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\renewcommand{\turnthepage}{\itshape [Please turn over]}
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
        \begin{shaded}
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
        \end{shaded}
    }\vspace{-5pt}
}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
    \begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}

\def\hyph{-\penalty0\hskip0pt\relax}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{\Large Steve Waugh} \\
        Ph.D. Student, University of Adelaide & allrounder@gmail.com / (999) 534-9194\\
    \end{tabular*}
    \\
    


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \resheading{Work Experience}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \begin{itemize} 
        
        \item \ressubheading{Graduate Research Assistant}{}{SY Simulation Center(in collaboration with OperaHouse),Perth}
        {May 2015 -- Present}

        
        \begin{itemize}
            \resitem{ E.. }
        \end{itemize}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \resitem{ .. }
        \end{itemize}   
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \resitem{ .. }
        \end{itemize}   
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \resitem{ .. }
        \end{itemize} 
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \resitem{ ..}
        \end{itemize} 
        
        \item \ressubheading{Junior Research Fellow}{}{Melbourne Institute of Engineering Science and Technology}{May 1912 -- July 1914}    
        \begin{itemize}
            \resitem{AB.. }
        \end{itemize}   
        \item \ressubheading{Summer Research Fellow}{}{Sydney Institute of Science, Sydney}
        {May 1913 -- July 1913}
        
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The incorrect alignment is this:
[image]

I would like to have the bullet points beside the bold lines. It would be great if someone can help me out with that. I don't want to change to another format all together, I would prefer to have the issue resolved in this particular format of the resume.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}[t]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Could you elaborate a little, on where to use that? I tried using that around \item without any success. Thanks..

Comment: just add `[t]`  to your tabular so they align on the first row not their vertical centre

Comment: That's not working. It totally destroys the alignment. Do I need any other package?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it in 2 steps:

1. Move \item to the definition of ressubheading. And create 2 tables instead of 1.

   ```
       \newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
           \item 
           \begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
               \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
           \end{tabular*}
           \begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
               \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
           \end{tabular*}
           \vspace{-6pt}
       }
   ```
2. Remove \item before using \ressubheading.

   ```
       \ressubheading{Graduate Research Assistant}{}{SY Simulation Center(in collaboration with OperaHouse), Perth}
       {May 2015 -- Present}
   ```

Not sure if this is the right way, but it'll do what you want.